# Trying to debug /etc/init.d/named, no output, replace > /dev/null with /var/log/named.log?

Tags: shell, services, named

I'm trying to debug named, when I try:

```
[root@test master]# service named start
Starting named:  

                                      [FAILED]
```

it fails silently, so I tried:

```
sed -i 's/\/dev\/null/\/var\/log\/named.log/g' /etc/init.d/named
```

Since I don't know shell script, but I know some stuff like what redirects do.

sed worked, I checked and made sure the changes happened
But /var/log/named.log remains empty. I don't understand why or how to proceed.

Comment: If the original lines have `>/dev/null`, you should change `>` to `>>`. This way it will append to the log file, not replace it each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of modifying the init script, investigate what debugging options are already provided with the software.

You have not specified what Linux distribution you're using. However, I can suggest the following based on CentOS 6:

1: the man page for `named` shows these debug options for the named daemon:

> ```
>    -d debug-level
>        Set the daemon’s debug level to debug-level. Debugging traces from
>        named become more verbose as the debug level increases.
>
>    -g Run the server in the foreground and force all logging to stderr.
> ```

2: the correct way of passing these options to the daemon is to modify `/etc/sysconfig/named`, and specify what command-line options you need passed to the daemon in the OPTIONS variable. The `/etc/sysconfig/named` file gets sourced in the init script, before running the `named` daemon.

Look for the line with OPTIONS=, uncomment it, and edit it to show as follows:

```
OPTIONS="-g"
```

3: Now start the daemon using the init script ; the script should stay in the foreground and the daemon's output should appear in the window.

Here is an example of the effect of enabling the "-g" option in my testing:

Without any modification to OPTIONS:

```
[user@mycentos6box ~]# /etc/init.d/named start
Starting named:                                            [  OK  ]
[user@mycentos6box ~]#
```

Modifying OPTIONS as per above:

```
[user@mycentos6box ~]# /etc/init.d/named start
Starting named:     24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.963 starting BIND 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.23.rc1.el6_5.1 -u named -g
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.963 built with '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--sharedstatedir=/var/lib' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--with-libtool' '--localstatedir=/var' '--enable-threads' '--enable-ipv6' '--with-pic' '--disable-static' '--disable-openssl-version-check' '--with-dlz-ldap=yes' '--with-dlz-postgres=yes' '--with-dlz-mysql=yes' '--with-dlz-filesystem=yes' '--with-gssapi=yes' '--disable-isc-spnego' '--with-docbook-xsl=/usr/share/sgml/docbook/xsl-stylesheets' '--enable-fixed-rrset' 'build_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'host_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'target_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS= -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' 'CPPFLAGS= -DDIG_SIGCHASE'
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.963 ----------------------------------------------------
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.963 BIND 9 is maintained by Internet Systems Consortium,
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.963 Inc. (ISC), a non-profit 501(c)(3) public-benefit
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.963 corporation.  Support and training for BIND 9 are
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.963 available at https://www.isc.org/support
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.963 ----------------------------------------------------
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.964 adjusted limit on open files from 4096 to 1048576
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.964 found 2 CPUs, using 2 worker threads
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.964 using up to 4096 sockets
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.967 loading configuration from '/etc/named.conf'
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.967 reading built-in trusted keys from file '/etc/named.iscdlv.key'
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.967 using default UDP/IPv4 port range: [1024, 65535]
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.968 using default UDP/IPv6 port range: [1024, 65535]
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.969 listening on IPv4 interface lo, 127.0.0.1#53
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.970 generating session key for dynamic DNS
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.970 sizing zone task pool based on 6 zones
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.972 using built-in DLV key for view _default
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.973 set up managed keys zone for view _default, file '/var/named/dynamic/managed-keys.bind'
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.973 Warning: 'empty-zones-enable/disable-empty-zone' not set: disabling RFC 1918 empty zones
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.973 automatic empty zone: 127.IN-ADDR.ARPA
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.973 automatic empty zone: 254.169.IN-ADDR.ARPA
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.973 automatic empty zone: 2.0.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.973 automatic empty zone: 100.51.198.IN-ADDR.ARPA
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.973 automatic empty zone: 113.0.203.IN-ADDR.ARPA
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.973 automatic empty zone: 255.255.255.255.IN-ADDR.ARPA
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.973 automatic empty zone: 0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.IP6.ARPA
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.973 automatic empty zone: D.F.IP6.ARPA
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.973 automatic empty zone: 8.E.F.IP6.ARPA
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.973 automatic empty zone: 9.E.F.IP6.ARPA
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.973 automatic empty zone: A.E.F.IP6.ARPA
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.973 automatic empty zone: B.E.F.IP6.ARPA
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.973 automatic empty zone: 8.B.D.0.1.0.0.2.IP6.ARPA
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.975 none:0: open: /etc/rndc.key: permission denied
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.975 couldn't add command channel 127.0.0.1#953: permission denied
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.975 none:0: open: /etc/rndc.key: permission denied
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.975 couldn't add command channel ::1#953: permission denied
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.975 ignoring config file logging statement due to -g option
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.975 zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.976 zone 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.976 zone 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.977 zone localhost.localdomain/IN: loaded serial 0
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.977 zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 0
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.977 managed-keys-zone ./IN: loaded serial 1
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.979 error (network unreachable) resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:503:ba3e::2:30#53
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.979 error (network unreachable) resolving './NS/IN': 2001:503:ba3e::2:30#53
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.979 error (network unreachable) resolving 'dlv.isc.org/DNSKEY/IN': 2001:500:2f::f#53
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.979 error (network unreachable) resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:500:2f::f#53
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.979 error (network unreachable) resolving './NS/IN': 2001:500:2f::f#53
24-Nov-2014 20:23:28.979 running
```

I can press CTRL-C to stop the daemon:

```
^C
24-Nov-2014 20:23:34.247 shutting down
24-Nov-2014 20:23:34.248 no longer listening on 127.0.0.1#53
24-Nov-2014 20:23:34.250 exiting
                           [  OK  ]
[user@mycentos6box ~]#
```